# Html.Action renders the partial menu inside with different link routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, child-actions

I render a menu widget inside the header of a master layout.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Html.Action("Menu", "Menu", new { area = "Application" })
```

**FullMenu.cshtml**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span></a></li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tests", "Index" })</li>
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

**MenuController.cs**

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        string controller = (string) ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        if (controller == "Projects")
        {
            return PartialView("StartMenu");
        }
        else
            return PartialView("FullMenu");
    }
}
```

This is the rendered output in the browser

[image]

Why has the rendered hyperlinks a modified Controller name? Even more those links applied the Controller name of the widget itself => "Menu"
Why is that?

Comment: Try @Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "Projects") in your FullMenu.cshtml

Comment: ok those links worked before, since I put them in the "widget" I need to declare the full route:         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "Projects", new { area = "Application" }, new { })</li> , thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the controller too in the menu route

```
@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "Projects")
```